# Swift get associated value in enums without switch

Tags: ios, swift

I have enum:

```
enum RetailDemandReturnOperation {
    case salesReturn(value: MSRetailSalesReturnRealm)
    case demand(value: MSRetailDemandRealm)
}
```

`MSRetailDemandRealm` and `MSRetailDemandRealm` are both implement same protocol, that have variables title and stats. I want to extract this values, but i don't care of which object actually stored in. Consider following:

```
 switch data! {
        case .salesReturn(let object):
            titleString = object.title
            statistics = object.stats
        case .demand(let object):
            titleString = object.title
            statistics = object.stats
          break
        }
```

I have to go in each enum value to get property of protocol. Is any way i can do it shorter and cleaner? Get associated value, no matter what it is, as long as it conforms to my protocol, and get protocol values?
Thanks.

Comment: @Palle an example would be great :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add a property to your enum that returns the protocol. For example:

```
enum RetailDemandReturnOperation {
    case salesReturn(value: MSRetailSalesReturnRealm)
    case demand(value: MSRetailDemandRealm)

    var realm: MSRetailRealm {
        switch self {
        case .salesReturn(let realm):
            return realm
        case .demand(let realm):
            return realm
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to access those properties on a specific value of the enum, just use:

```
let operation = RetailDemandReturnOperation.salesReturn(value: MSRetailSalesReturnRealm())
let title = operation.realm.title
```

Comment: I think this will be the best solution. there can't be a "built in" way to do this because the associated value for each case could have a unrelated type. Therefor you are going to have to write your own function (or calculated variable) for getting the associated value, in order to specify the type (in your case a protocol, alternatively it could be a common parent class). So I don't think the switch can be completely avoided, but encapsulating like this means that you only need to write one switch :)

Comment: @daltonclaybrook thanks, though its sad that there is not easier way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Since `RetailDemandReturnOperation` always has the associated value for `MSRetailRealm`, you can give it a new property of type `RetailDemandReturnOperation`. Then, you can get rid of the the associated value in your enum.

```
enum RetailDemandReturnOperation {
    case salesReturn
    case demand
}

protocol MSRetailRealm {
    var stats: Int { get set }
    var title: String { get set }
    var operation: RetailDemandReturnOperation { get }
}

struct MSRetailDemandRealm: MSRetailRealm {
    //.. your old code
    var operation: RetailDemandReturnOperation { return .demand }
}

struct MSRetailSalesReturnRealm: MSRetailRealm {
    //.. your old code
    var operation: RetailDemandReturnOperation { return .salesReturn }
}
```

Now you can access `stats` and `title` no matter what operation it is. And if you care about the operation, simply access the `operation` property.

```
func example(object: MSRetailRealm) {
    let titleString = object.title
    switch object.operation {
        case .salesReturn:
            break
        case .demand:
            break
    }
}
```